# Change a string variable into a set of categorical variables in one command

Tags: regression, stata, dummy-variable

Say I have a categorical variable, for example a country column in a table.
How can I quickly add dummy variables for each category--WITH A RELEVANT NAME?

So if the column is for country, the variable for whether the person lives in the USA would be called USA not `country16` or something.

Comment: Watch out: country names with spaces won''t be legal variable names. `"United States"` would be one such.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy:

```
/* Make some fake data */
sysuse auto, clear
gen make_only = subinstr(lower(word(make,1)),".","",.)

/* Create meaningful dummies */
levelsof make_only, clean local(makes)
foreach m of local makes {
    gen `m' = cond(make_only=="`m'",1,0)
}
```

However, it is probably easier to just use factor variables notation:

```
sencode make_only, label(make_only) replace
reg price i.make_only
list make price if make_only=="amc":make_only
```

Regression output will be nicely labeled, you don't create extra variables, and it's easy enough to refer to particular values.

---

`sencode` is written by Roger Newson and is available from SSC.

Comment: @Dan Did this help you out?